# configuration to listen-on different depending on the domain asked

Tags: dns, bind

I want to configure bind such that the host served differ depending on the domain asked.

the use case is the following: it must respond to anyone if the requested domain is in the domain my server is authoritative for, and must accept to respond to a limited range of IP addresses otherwise. (I don't want a open recursive resolver)

I think this should be possible through the ''listen-for'' directive, but i'm unsure.

Answer (score 1):

The BIND keyword you are looking for is `allow-recursion`.  Here is a sample configuration similar to what you want: http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/#master

Basically:

```
options {
 directory "/var/named";
 allow-recursion {192.168.1.0/24;};
};
zone "." {
 type hint;
 file "root.servers";
};
zone "example.com" in{
 type master;
 file "master/master.example.com";
};
```

If you want, say, "www.example.com" to have the IP, say, 10.1.2.3 when queried from the Internet but the IP 192.168.1.2 when queried from your office, this is called *split horizon DNS*